# Wordpress Update Option is setting value as Simple XML Help

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to store an option value in the wp_options table by using update_option, however it goes in as SimpleXML Object when all I want is a normal string of numbers/letters...

I have this:

$id = '1f84705816652deccc97a53acd21b86bcf91f264';

update_option('box_id', $id);

So now I can't pull this value out by using $id = get_option('box_id'); because it is a simpleXML object...

Anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just fixed it by type casting it like so:
update_option('box_id'(string)$id);